# What is the wip0 register in the context of ARM64 architecture?

Tags: assembly, arm64, cpu-registers

Say, in the following disassembled instructions:

```
lbl:
    ldaxr     x8, [x9]
    add       x8, x8, #1
    stlxr     wip0, x8, [x9]
    cbnz      wip0, lbl
```

What is `wip0`?

Comment: @Hi c00000fd, was the answer correct and satisfactory, and if not, what could be done for improving it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wip0` is in fact an alias for `w16`, see section "6.3.1 Use of IP0 and IP1 by the linker"of the Procedure [Call Standard for the Arm® 64-bit Architecture
(AArch64)](https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecs452/docs/rpi4b/aapcs64.pdf)

Comment: These are indeed aliases, defined as such: `xip0` = `x16`, `xip1` = `x17`, `wip0` = `w16`, `wip1`=`w17`. XIP stands for X-Intra-Procedure call scratch register and WIP, W-Intra-Procedure. X=64-bit version of ARM64 registers and W=32-bit. "Intra-Procedure" are special volatile registers that are used to pass internal parameters between functions.

Comment: Additionally, `x18` is a special register. On Windows, it has an alias `XPR`. In user-mode, it points to the `_TEB` struct; and in kernel mode - to `_KPCR` struct. (WinDbg currently has a bug that doesn't display `x18` correctly.)